# Open Apple Wallet whilst Maps satnav is running

Tags: ios, wallet, navigation

This tends to occur when trying to buy fuel whilst on a journey. The action I'm trying to use is double-click the home button [yes, I still have one of those, an SE2, my FaceID 13 Max lasted 24 hours before I sent it back]

When I only had a single bank card in my Wallet this was less of an issue, holding the phone to the NFC device would auto-open the Wallet.

Now I also have store cards in it, which are not part of any payment structure, merely contain a bar code the store's system can read to register my purchases for points. When Apple Maps is running I can't get Wallet to come to the front. It just opens the map instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of lateral thinking got me out of this.

Add Wallet to the Control Centre. Then it's available with a swipe whilst the navigation is still running.

[image]

For an additional way to get to it, make Control Centre spring up using Back Tap.

[image]